# Array of ClosedRange<Int> and ReverseCollection<ClosedRange<Int>>

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, range, reverse

I can easily iterate through the elements of a closed range. Ditto for the elements of the `reversed()` of a closed range. However, these two constructs happen to have different types, such as `ClosedRange<Int>` for the former and `ReverseCollection<ClosedRange<Int>>`.

Suppose I need to have some kind of collection (e.g., an array) including both ranges and reversed ranges: how would I go about it?

Example:

```
let aaa = 1...3
let bbb = (4...6).reversed()
let ranges = [aaa,bbb]  // heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred of type '[Any]'
for range in ranges {
  for item in range {
    print(item)
  }
}
```

Simply declaring `ranges` to be of type `[Sequence]` or `[Collection]` does not work, because "Protocol 'Sequence' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert all elements to the same type either `Array` or `AnySequence`, depending on your performance concerns. `Array` would create new storage but when the sequence is reversed may have better performance. `AnySequence` merely forwards operations to its base class, thus depending on your sequence size, could be computationally complex.

```swift
let aaa = Array(1...3)
let bbb = Array((4...6).reversed())

let ranges = [aaa, bbb]
for range in ranges {
    for item in range {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of either solution? Why the map and not just an Array() initializer? Are we creating new storage here (I seem to recall that reversed() does not create new storage, but probably that is not so relevant for ranges)?

Comment: `map` and `Array` would both create new storage. I suspect `AnySequence` would merely forward operations to its base class, thus depending on your sequence size, could be computationally complex.

Comment: @LeoDabus it was more out of preference than anything. Updated to use `Array` which makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AnySequence`:

```
let aaa = AnySequence(1...3)
let bbb = AnySequence((4...6).reversed())
let ranges = [aaa, bbb] // ranges is [AnySequence<Int>]
for range in ranges {
  for item in range {
    print(item)
  }
}
```